# The tSystem component does not display correctly - Talend

Tags: unix, talend

I use the tSystem component on my job talend, which runs the command "diff out-file.txt out-file2.txt", only the result is not displayed correctly.

Example:
I have 2 files, outfile and oufile2, outfile contains :
line1
line2
line3
line6,
and outfile2 contains :
line1
line2
line4
line5

But the output of my tSystem sometimes displays :
3.4c3.4
< line4
< line5.

While on my cmd I have:
3.4c3.4
< line4
< line5
"---"
"> line3"
"> line6"

Does anyone know what’s causing this?

Comment: did you try using a tFileCompare component ?

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa Yes, but a tfile component only displays if two files are different or not. I also want the lines number and lines, the unix diff command is perfect for this but it seems to work badly on my talend...